# PowerDesigner 15 - Generated XML schema - XML model - How to generate "interfaces" objects?

Tags: xml, xsd, powerdesigner

I'm trying to generate XSD files from a MOO file, but I don't obtain the complex types ("xs:complexType" in XSD files).

So I've generated a XML model (MSX) from the MOO file (by selecting Tools→Generate XML Model (Ctrl+Shift+M) to open the XML Model Generation Options Window), and then it's OK to obtain the complex types, but I don't obtain the "interfaces" objects.

Is there someone who could help me to generate theses "interfaces" objects, please ?

Regards,
Cyrille

Comment: If I understand correctly the first part... initially, you did not have the classes generated as complex types, until you selected the `Generate Classes as: Elements with complex types`generation options. Correct?

Comment: Why do you want to generate `Interfaces`? To share Attribute, Property, Method? Could you use an Abstract class instead of an Interface?

Comment: More exactly : initially, I didn't have the classes generated as complex types, until I generated a MSX file + CTRL+G to generate the XSD file.

Comment: If I don't use a MSX file and if I change the current object langage to have a "XML - Schema langage" and if I use CTRL-G to generate the XSD files, then these XSD files don't have the "complex types". How bizarre...

Comment: And you're right; in theory, I don't need to generate Interfaces :)